# Add views inside Constraint Layout and set them full screen programmatically

Tags: android, layout, constraints, fullscreen

I spent some hours adding a imageview inside a ConstraintLayout and setting it to fullscreen size.

This is my actual code for add the image inside the Constraint Layout:

```
final ConstraintLayout constraitLayout = (ConstraintLayout)activity.findViewById(layout_xml);
    constraitLayout.addView(mImage,0);
    ConstraintSet set1 = new ConstraintSet();
    set1.clone(constraitLayout);
    set1.connect(mImage.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, constraitLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, 0);
    set1.connect(mImage.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, constraitLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, 0);
    set1.connect(mImage.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, constraitLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 0);
    set1.connect(mImage.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, constraitLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0);
    set1.applyTo(constraitLayout);
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: is is necessary to use constraint layout if you want to set imageview full screen ^

Comment: Yes, is necessary to use the constraint layout. Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the issue is you didn't set width and height to your image view so by default wrap_content is taken for both. So setting them both 0dp will fix the issue . Add these lines to set the width and height to 0dp.

```
 mImage.setLayoutParams(
            new LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams(
                    0,0));
```

One more thing , instead of getting parent id as constraintLayout.getId() you can use  ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID. So final code looks like

```
 mImage.setLayoutParams(
            new LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams(
                    0,0));
    constraitLayout.addView(mImage,0);
    ConstraintSet set1 = new ConstraintSet();
    set1.clone(constraitLayout);
    set1.connect(mImage.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP, 0);
    set1.connect(mImage.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.LEFT, 0);
    set1.connect(mImage.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 0);
    set1.connect(mImage.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0);
    set1.applyTo(constraitLayout);
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Velmurugan V that is what I was looking for.

Comment: welcome @user1116665 i have edited your title to increase question view so that people can get benefit  from this question